# Ruby SQLite wrong argument type

Tags: ruby, sqlite, rvm

Code `@db = SQLite3::Database.new 'db.db'` works perfectly with ruby-1.9.3-p194 and returns error with ruby-2.0.0-p353 (rvm 1.24.7):

```
wrong argument type nil (expected Hash) (TypeError)
```

I can't googling any solution.

**UPD**: There is no error with irb. Only with my own code:

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'sqlite3'

class Model
  attr_reader :files, :last

  def initialize(dbPath = 'photo.db', tags = '', lastID = 0)
    @tags = tags
    @lastID = lastID
    $log.debug() {"Loading database: #{dbPath}..."}
    @db = SQLite3::Database.new dbPath
  end
...
```

It produces this trace in log:

```
I, [2013-12-29T12:03:30.586180 #8961]  INFO -- : ---===== S T A R T E D =====---
I, [2013-12-29T12:03:30.587922 #8961]  INFO -- : Config /home/michael/Projects/Ruby/SPS/config.yml loaded
D, [2013-12-29T12:03:30.588072 #8961] DEBUG -- : Loading database: /home/michael/.local/share/shotwell/data/photo.db...
F, [2013-12-29T12:03:30.588207 #8961] FATAL -- : wrong argument type nil (expected Hash) (TypeError)
/home/michael/Projects/Ruby/SPS/model.rb:11:in `initialize'
/home/michael/Projects/Ruby/SPS/model.rb:11:in `new'
/home/michael/Projects/Ruby/SPS/model.rb:11:in `initialize'
/home/michael/Projects/Ruby/SPS/controller.rb:11:in `new'
/home/michael/Projects/Ruby/SPS/controller.rb:11:in `initialize'
./main.rb:10:in `new'
./main.rb:10:in `'
```

Comment: If you think something wrong, you can log [here](https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/issues)

Comment: Here is the same [issue](https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/issues/88), but its solution (reinstalling gem) not working for me.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full backtrace; what file/line number is this error occurring on?

Comment: The heroku guys [HERE][1] experienced a similar issue and they seem to have gotten beyond it by reinstalling the Ruby Sequel gem.


  [1]: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-taps/issues/4

Comment: Sequel installing, deinstalling has no effect on the error.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it with replacing in executable script `#!/usr/bin/ruby` with `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`.